# Problem as a guest on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, comments, unregistered-users

How can I comment on the post that I've asked as guest?

Comment: There is a cookie based system that tries to keep "guest" visits hooked together, but it is perforce fragile. Once that breaks you'll have to do as Grace Note suggests.

Answer (score 3):

If you can provide proof of ownership of the guest account, send an email to `team@stackoverflow.com` detailing your plight. They can then merge the account with yours, which gives you ownership of the post and thus the ability to add comments once again. You'll also regain any reputation you may have earned as that guest account.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you've given us a valid email you can reinstate your cookie.

On the [login page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login), as long as you are not logged in as a user already, click the section below:

> If you've forgotten or lost your login information
>
> ### click here to recover your account

Comment: Is it possible to merge that topic with my current account in this way?

Comment: @kvph email the address at the bottom of every page we serve